# Select nearest values around a certain value in column

Tags: pandas, select, conditional-statements

I have the following df and I need to find all values which are equal or nearest to 660 in column value.
In detail this means I must iterate somehow through the column value to find all these 660 or nearest values. The values in column value are in a range from 1 to (the end varies) and when the end is reached the values start again from 1. Finally, I must select the entire row of all other columns where value == 660 (or neareest). I have more or less a 'helper' column helper which has the same value during a value range of 1 to end. It could be helpfull to get the result (column help is always 0 or 1). Here is the df example:

```
helper      value
0         1
.
.
.
0       647
0       649
0       652  
0       654
0       656
0       659
0       661
0       663 
0       665
0       667
0       669
0       672
0       674
0       676
0       678
0       681
.
.
.
0       1000
1       1
.
.
.
1       647
1       649
1       652
1       654
1       656
1       659
1       661
1       663
1       665
1       667
1       669
1       672
1       674
1       676
1       678
1       681
.
.
1       1500
0       1
.
.
.
0       645
0       647
0       650
0       652
0       654
0       656
0       658
0       661
0       663
0       665
0       667
0       669
0       672
0       674
0       676
0       679
.
.
.
0       980
```

Thanks for any help or hints!

Comment: first: a smaller df please, second, how near to 660 are you looking for?

Comment: as near as possible. and if 660 exist take this value

Comment: Then just substract each row with 660 and find the abs() min value of the difference.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough info for a correct answer. What is the size of the dataframe? Also what do you mean by nearest? The solution to "where value == 660" can be done by applying a mask to the pandas series.

Something like `df = df[(df['value'] == 660)]` should do.

While if you have a range of numbers you can use boolean operators for the mask:

```
mask = df.value > 650 & df.value < 670
df = df[mask]
```

Let me know if this is what you are looking for

Comment: I only need one value which is the nearest, not a range. I will try your hint, thanks!